# What makes a good question, and ability to ask them again and again?

Tags: discussion, reputation, questions

Beyond questions that are closed as not constructive or unclear, what makes a good question and a person able to ask them over and over?

I have two examples. This question is has a score of 137. It has a certain intelligence in how it's asked but as one user says “+1 for `@"This is a duck"`! “

- [String replacement in Objective-C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/668228/string-replacement-in-objective-c)

I answered a question with some similarity, it asked for the correct way, but showed a definite trace of research as it outlined the method it was asking about more or less.  It was from the same user.  And I thought it was a good question.

- [Passing data between views?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23409914/passing-data-between-views)

To me both questions are fine. They don't need down votes. But what is the thing that makes a good question and the ability to ask them again and again and earn rep?

You take a risk when you ask a question. I'm taking a risk, I don't need a bunch of upvotes and i'd hope I don't get a bunch of downvotes only because I'd like to be able to continue asking questions. You can't easily delete a question like you can an answer if you find out you asked a bad question.

[String replacement in Objective-C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/668228/string-replacement-in-objective-c) is an older question dating back to 2009.  But not every question is found. Simple questions can be good questions in the rep system as shown.  But does it dig deeper? Is there a quality to a question that is good, makes it found etc?

Edit:

In reading the first answer I think there is something about having productive conversation.

This user has answered very few questions.  Is asking not answering a factor in a good question?

Comment: Look at the age of the 1st question. It's had a lot more time to accumulate votes.

Comment: Related: [How do beginners (like me) actually ask good questions and not get our accounts terminated?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255996/how-do-beginners-like-me-actually-ask-good-questions-and-not-get-our-accounts)

Comment: Obligatory link to **[How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)**.

Comment: [String replacement in Objective-C](http://stackoverflow.com/q/668228/456814) ***is not a good question by today's standards***. It's way too broad, and would attract downvotes due to lacking effort on the part of the asker in attempting to solve his own problem.

Comment: I didn't think through that the standards could be changing beyond what was said "It's had a lot more time to accumulate votes" but my question and example seems to bring that point out so good point.

Answer (score 3):

Sounds more like you're asking

> What makes a popular question?

Obviously if I knew the answer to this I wouldn't share it but ask them myself so I could bathe in reputation. I can list some factors that might help to push you in this direction:

- Interesting

This is closely related to *useful* not always the same. For example [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19416644/how-can-a-java-variable-be-different-from-itself) is interesting but not really useful.

- Useful

This is like [the question you linked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/668228/string-replacement-in-objective-c): a common problem will automatically attract more searches and thus view/upvotes/stars.

- Brevity

Short questions are easy to digest and thus more people will read all of it and remain interested.

- Technology area

A common problem in Javascript, Java or Objective-C will get more attention than one in assembly or COBOL. This shifts with the languages market.

- Time of asking

The majority of SO is probably European and American. If you pose a question at 7AM European time (23 - 24 PM US time) less people will see your post. Same goes for asking it on NYE or a similar date.

- Age of post

A post that has been around for 5 years (like your example) will obviously have a bigger chance at gathering views than the one you posted yesterday.

I'm sure there are more factors to take into account but these are the ones that came to mind immediately.

Comment: I don't think i'm asking what makes popular questions. Have you read any of the users questions or my answer to him(which was accepted).  I think there is more to it. he earned 500 or so rep on that question but has earned 10,000 about rep total on questions.

Comment: Many of his top questions are posed in '09 or '10, are short, in very hot tags (iPhone development started around that time so if you're the first to ask the question, everyone else - in theory - that gets into that branch of development will end up on your post) and are about an actual problem. If you ask lots of these questions, you'll end up with a lot of popular posts.

Comment: so your answer is asking a lot of questions on hot topics over the years. this makes sense as a way to earn rep and this is in part a rep question.  But is that all there is to what makes it a good question, why it's not down voted for example.

Comment: "*I think there is more to it*" What is it exactly that you think? I doubt there's any fairies or voting fraud going on so the only option left is that he simply posed a lot of popular questions.

Comment: Well why do you think it should have been downvoted?

Comment: this user is just an example. this is not a question about this user. Let us pretend we are him or somebody else, starting out on stack, and staying on stack asking questions. Could we expect just asking questions on popular topics to earn us rep? A pattern of asking a lot of questions can lead to a lot of down votes not just up votes no?

Comment: So the question stands. I don't think random popular questions is the answer here. I'm asking about consistency.  And it doesn't have to yield 10,000 rep. but consistently good questions that go up in rep, what makes that?

Comment: I don't base my up- and downvotes on the user's question history, that would make no sense. I doubt people even watch a new user's profile unless the question is in such poor quality that you want to look into flagging. And no, just asking questions on hot topics is probably not enough: your question should also be interesting/common (and not a duplicate) and whatever else is in the list above.

Comment: I didn't suggest it was based on the users question history. i read stack profiles and browse questions and answers at times.

Comment: Honestly I have no idea what kind of answer you expect. There is no magic "get lots of upvotes" button so obviously he simply asked many popular questions. I'll leave the discussion at that since I've said anything I could say, maybe someone else is able to provide you with the answer you want.

Comment: This discussion is about me saying i don't think this is an answer. Your correct that this type and a lot of meta questions don't have 'an answer' but i don't think popular question is an answer because i asked about how to ask consistently good questions. And just asking questions on hot tags can be suicide if your questions are not well received.

Comment: In particular you said "Sounds more like you're asking

What makes a popular question?" i disagree. if you edit the post i'll delete my comments.

Answer (score 1):

I think the most significant factor is age.

It seems to me the older questions are more popular simply because they've had more time to accrue views. Also, when they were first posted, there were fewer questions on each topic competing for views.

The first question you linked to was asked way back in 2009, and back then, any question which wasn't totally stupid would gets tons of views and upvotes. It doesn't actually make them **good** questions, merely OK ones. Similar questions being asked now (assuming they don't get closed as a duplicate) would be lucky to get a single up-vote and a few dozen views.

People just joining now will have to work much harder for reputation that those who joined 5+ years ago for the simple reason that questions they could have answered or asked have already been discussed.

Of course there are exceptions to this rule as technology is updated and there are new topics on which to ask/answer questions.

Comment: I think this answer has a valid point.  Stack is only a few years old but it must have been a different world when those tricky newer programmer questions were still all valid to ask since the site didn't have them logged on here as questions yet or as frequently.

Answer (score -1):

In my opinion often the best questions are the worst by community standards, like the one you linked which was upvoted to death whose whole body consists of just:

> What is the best way to replace a character is a string in Objective-C for
>   iPhone SDK?

And that's the type of question which can easily be closed depending on who looks at it first. It's lazy, it's asking "what is best?" which could be interpreted as too broad or opinionated depending on context, it doesn't provide any kind of MVCE. It's just a one-liner question on what the best way is to do things from someone who showed no attempt at researching this for himself/herself.

I actually believe these to be the best questions for the site, because most of my bookmarked links to SO fit this category because they're the type of "sand" that often generates the finest "pearls". *"What's the fastest way to do this? What's the best way to do that?"* and sometimes just really lazy questions like, *"How do I do this even though I haven't shown any effort in researching it for myself? Should I do things this way or that way?"* Those are the canonical type of questions that I find worth linking to in order to refer back to answers in the future because I end up finding myself asking the same kinds of basic/lazy questions.

Those are fantastic questions because they're the kinds of questions that cross people's minds often. They're popular because most of us have lazy questions, not meticulously detailed, product/engine-specific questions researched to death with MCVEs highlighting a very site-specific issue related to a very specific piece of code. To ask an elaborate question like that would often limit its scope and interest to a very narrow range of people. Simply asking, "What is best way to do this? How do I do that? Why do people often do this? Why do people often believe that?" is often going to hit the broadest audience, especially if someone decides to provide a nice answer.

The trick to me seems to be to find a lazy but popular question like this which doesn't get closed and manages to get a lot of views and up-votes from people who like it as soon as possible to get some momentum going.

Comment: This seems to suggest one does not need to read any manual at all and that's okay because all answers to [even the most basic principles of some languages](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48235888) ought to be found on SO.

Comment: For me personally, most of these types aren't so interesting as ones like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc since I can't find answers to those types of questions so easily in other resources -- they're the types where I'm looking for popular opinion from experienced people. But they're in a similar kind of vein: "what is best?"

Comment: But beginners might find more in the RTFM category more interesting. For me it's also dependent on the quality and experience behind the answers. This question could have just been a run-of-the-mill question except Mysticial and other experts answered it with the most beautiful breakdown of how branch misprediction works: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11227809/why-is-it-faster-to-process-a-sorted-array-than-an-unsorted-array/11237235#11237235. So I often think it's the answers that make a question great, not the question.

Comment: Post such a superior quality answer to the question in my first comment and I'll happily agree with you. There is an old adage "there is no such thing as a stupid question", but there are lots of posts that come pretty damn close.

Comment: Another fav: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34365746/whats-the-fastest-way-to-convert-hex-to-integer-in-c. Cause I thought that would be a boring question, and asked at the wrong time of day, might have just been DVed to death with people suggesting to profile. But that time it was lucky and managed to invite some experts doing the most elaborate assembly analysis and benchmarks and profiling with graphs to compare techniques. I got lots of these and the questions aren't so good, but it's the answers that made all the diff.

Comment: @usr2564301 For that one I actually think the question is too good by community standards! :-D I generally think the best chance of inviting a decent answer would have to aim a bit broader, like, "What are the uses for bitwise and, and why would anyone use that?" or something to this effect. Then maybe someone can come in writing up the most beautiful answer on the uses of bitwise and, the history of bitwise operations, something of this sort. That one question is too specific to the op's (mis)understanding of `bitwise and` inside of a parentheses.

Comment: @usr2564301 Was thinking about this a bit more, and I can't perfectly place my finger on the common denominator of what makes a question and its answers interesting to me personally... but definitely it's not the MCVE ones where the answerers are effectively debugging for the OP. Those I think are boring to just about everyone, since they're too specific to the OP's broken code and his/her misassumptions (too lacking in generality), and everyone's answer basically becomes the same. There's no subjectivity or deep experience in the answers, so it's like a FGITW echo setting.

Comment: @usr2564301 There was a recent question that was closed that I was disappointed to see closed here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48090782/how-to-best-write-a-voxel-engine-in-c-with-performance-in-mind. That's an example of a crappy question that was starting to generate interesting content from enthusiastic people in spite of being open for such a short period of time. Seems lika missed opportunity... way I see it is the site is always going to have one constant: student types just wanting people to fix their broken code and/or do their homework and correct their incorrect assumptions..

Comment: I see that as inevitable -- the site is always going to be halfway perceived as like a "help me now" site by many, but the main thing I'm hoping for is that in spite of that constant, there will still be people around to contribute interesting content... but I often see such opportunities missed when the questions that are starting to generate it get closed, and then I'm back to looking at a lot of my "fix my broken code" questions again.