# How do beginners (like me) actually ask good questions and not get our accounts terminated?

Tags: discussion

I've heard all about if you ask poor questions, your account gets terminated. But with all the questions I've asked they gotten down-voted. Since I am beginner and all you guys are more advanced, how do I ask a question without being booted off this site?

Comment: [**How to ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: dont include a youtube link instead of a cogent description; dont use the phrases "its urgent", "please help" or "due at noon"; pretend you are talking to experts and want to be taken seriously; avoid words like "n00b", bro, cuz and like (as in 'its like...then Im like...but the foo is like while the bar is like...'). dont use emoticons; include actual code, not a link to a screenshot of your code; tidy up your code - it will be on display under your name forever.  Create a name.

Comment: The [help] has valuable info, take some time to read it. Using [so] is very easy, you just need to follow some basic rules. After you learn, you'll only profit; otherwise it's all tears and drama ;)

Comment: Is this really true? Accounts get terminated for poor questions? I would have thought they only get terminated for misbehaviour. The voting and closing systems are there to deal with poor questions.

Comment: @EJP By "terminate", the OP means banned from asking questions.

Comment: @Mysticial Thank you, and does that really happen on quality grounds?

Comment: Before asking a question, search the stackoverflow.com index site (named google.com) for possible already existing answers to your question.

Comment: @DwB I had already checked the Help Center, which is where I would expect to find this sort of thing. Nothing there about account termination whatsoever.

Comment: I have to say that I suspect that in some (moderately rare) cases there is some sort of organized effort to downvote certain posts, either by a group working together or by someone who has several accounts that he uses in unison.  I say this because I have seen some fairly reasonable (though clearly newbie) questions viciously downvoted and closed within minutes, when other even poorer questions remain open.  I have no idea why someone would want to do this, but the voting seems hard to explain otherwise.

Comment: @HotLicks That happens when the question gets linked in a chatroom. It's very common and is usually done by someone who wants help closing or deleting something. (PHP room I'm looking at you :D) And in the process of doing that, the target gets downvoted by multiple people. It happens both ways, getting linked in chat can lead to a burst of upvotes.

Comment: @Mysticial - OK, that explains a lot.  Seems like a bad thing, but I suppose there's nothing you can do about it.  (The "targets" I've seen have generally been quite innocuous and not at all worthy of such ire.)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A few tips from what I would like someone that asks a question to consider:

- state the problem clear (Most important in my opinion)
- add a code example that is EXACTLY (or almost) what is needed to replicate the problem (not 124141 lines of code that has nothing to do with the problem).
- tell us what you tried
- if you got an error, tell the lines where it occur and what have you tried to figure out the cause.
- if your question is a theoretical one and is indeed fitted for *StackOverflow*, do a search (favorite search engine or *StackOverflow* search) to see if the question was not answered already.
- when you post code, spend 2-3 minutes to format it so it will be easier to read.
- use relevant tags so you will attract people who could answer.
- if you are not a native english speaker or confident in your language skill, try translating your question from English to your native language and see how well it gets translated. In most cases this could improve your question a bit at least.

This might seem a long list at first, but it will become easier to follow them faster than you think.

Respecting those points is needed because:

- *StackOverflow* is not a freelancing website. An imperative tone will most likely attract down-votes faster then you can blink.
- Even if *StackOverflow* is filled with magical creatures that can read minds and predict that *"a missing semicolon"* is about to happen, most of us are not mythical and there is no tale about us. So we need all those information to be able to give a good answer that will actually help you.

Comment: Whats funny Is that I don't receive this reputation.

Comment: As far as I know, on **Meta StackOverflow** you don't get reputation. Neither did I get any. But I assure you, you will get on other websites under *StackExchange*.

Comment: Don't just "state" the problem, *characterize* it.  This requires some investigation.  You want to collect the "hard" data (exception message and stack trace in the  typical case) but you also need to collect *real* values for the inputs and outputs entering and leaving the problem code segment.  Often, when you do this, you end up answering your own question before you post it, and, if not, the question will be much better received.

Answer (score 15):

First and foremost, try to avoid asking a question altogether.  In my opinion, most "bad" questions I see are questions that could've been avoided being asked if the asker put just slightly more effort into researching the problem.

There are over 7 million questions on StackOverflow.  If you're a beginner and writing in a common language, I'm guaranteeing your question is already answered somewhere on StackOverflow if you do just a little bit of searching.  How do you think I'm going to answer your bad question?  A little bit of experience, a little bit of looking at other questions on StackOverflow.

Questions not asked can't be downvoted.

---

Second, make sure your question has ALL the necessary information.

What's the actual problem?  Clearly state the actual problem in plain English that a non-programmer could understand.

What are the attempted solutions to the problem?  Clearly state the actual attempted solutions in plain English that a non-programmer could understand.

What's your code look like?  Show us your attempted code.  Even if you think your attempts are no where near correct, it could be that you're close.  It makes it easier for us to understand what you don't understand or what you're doing wrong if we see your attempts.

"But it didn't work" is not acceptable.  Things can not work in a myriad of different ways, and you need to explain in detail why they didn't work.

If your code isn't compiling, your compiler told you why.  So if you're going to ask the question, make it clear that the problem is that the code won't compile and post exactly what the compiler told you and make it clear which line numbers it referenced.

If your code is compiling but crashing, you're getting a stacktrace.  Post your stacktrace along with any lines it references.  But don't just post these over.  Most of the time, if you actually read these, the problem is CLEARLY AND EXPLICITLY described.  Nothing makes me downvote a question harder than a question that purely copied and pasted a stack trace that the asked didn't even bother to read (and I know they didn't, because if they did, it would've easily been fixed).

If your code is compiling, not crashing, but producing unexpected/unwanted/incorrect results, you've got a logic error.  This is where it's most important that you make your expected vs actual results very clear, and explain, in plain English, how it is the actual results should be arrived at.

---

Third, to assure yourself some upvotes, do all of the above... but also, do a lot more work on your own end before posting to StackOverflow.  Reduce the problem to the bare minimums.  Start commenting out lots of code.  Comment it all out until the problem goes away, uncomment back until it comes back.  Now you've narrowed it down exactly to one line.

Strip out all the code that's irrelevant to the problem.  Create a new project from scratch that replicates the error.  Nine times out of ten, by the time you do this, you've figured the problem out on your own and don't need to post a question.

Answer (score 6):

Pretend you've got your dream job and you're getting paid to solve whatever you're working on / whatever your question is and Stack Overflow is a community of your co-workers, including everyone up to the CEO of the company.

The rest of this post should follow fairly logically from just keeping the above in mind.

---

Asking bad questions will really damage your reputation at your company, but asking good questions will probably get you a fair amount of respect.

---

**Are you going to ask *them* to do it?** No, you're going to put in a ton of work yourself and only ask for help when you're really, really stuck.

**Are you going to give them a few hundred lines of code to debug for you?** No, you're going to debug it yourself, and if you really can't figure it out, you're going to do your absolute best to construct [a program of a dozen or so lines which reproduces the issue](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (sure, a dozen or so lines doesn't apply to **all** issues, but you'll be surprised how often it does).

**Are you going to ask a question they've already answered dozens / hundreds of times, or for which you can easily find the answer online?** No, you're going to search for the solution, rephrase your question, search again, rephrase it, search again, repeat a few more times, and make sure no-one's asked this question, or a similar enough one that will give you the answer to yours, before.

**Are you going to give them a vague description of the problem or waste their time with excessive details?** No, you're going to make sure you give exactly the required amount of information - nothing more, nothing less (but err on the side of more if you're not sure).

**Are you going to force everyone to read your entire question before being able to tell if it's in their domain of expertise?** No, you're going to put the summarize the question front and center so that's all one has to read to tell whether one might know the answer.

**Are you going to ask them where you can download the latest episode of Girls Gone Wild?** No (well, I hope not), you're going to make 101% sure whatever you ask is within [whatever guidelines they set up](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

**Are you going to direct programming questions to HR?** No, you're going to make sure you [address the question to the appropriate party (tag it correctly)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging).

**Are you going to just post your question without proofreading it?** No, you're going to read it again, and again. You're going to spell-check, grammar-check, guy-next-to-you-check, Google-difficult-words-check, make sure your formatting is perfect...-check, look at other people's questions to make sure your question is up to scratch and try to learn from the way they formatted the question...-check?, read [any resource you can find on formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)-mate... I mean check, and whatever else you can think of to make your question look as perfect as possible.

Answer (score 2):

**Read these pages from [the Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help)**:

- [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).
- [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).
- [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask).

Also, read this:

- [What is the proper way to approach SO as someone totally new to programming?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254572/what-is-the-proper-way-to-approach-so-as-someone-totally-new-to-programming/254579#254579).