# How can I make these two downvoted questions of mine better?

Tags: discussion, downvotes, specific-question, low-quality-posts, post-ban

I'm new to StackOverflow, and I want get better at asking good questions.

Recently, two of my questions have been down-voted:

- [Opening Text Files on Remote Linux Machine within Client-Installed Smultron](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23919775/opening-text-files-on-remote-linux-machine-within-client-installed-smultron)
- [Correct Path for Git Remote Add from Amazon EC2 Instance to OSX Client Machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23793657/correct-path-for-git-remote-add-from-amazon-ec2-instance-to-osx-client-machine)

In both of these cases, I feel like I'm following the [advice](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for asking good questions.

I would love an explanation as to what was wrong with these two questions, so that I can get better in the future. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Duplicate of [How do beginners (like me) actually ask good questions and not get our accounts terminated?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255996/how-do-beginners-like-me-actually-ask-good-questions-and-not-get-our-accounts)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the proper way to approach SO as someone totally new to programming?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254572/456814).

Comment: @Cupcake: Thanks. Those links are helpful, and I'll read through each one carefully. But I really would prefer someone to look at my specific down-voted questions (linked to above), and give me feedback on those specifically.

Comment: The first one isn't a programming question.  It's got at least one close vote that "Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming."  (You might look at something like emacs' tramp mode, by the way.)

Comment: Btw You are not really new user. You are registered for 4 months already ))).

Comment: @nicael That means nothing. People sign up all the time to favorite (save) questions or post one question every couple of months, and then *later* get more involved.

Comment: @Qix, I'm one of those. Member for well over a year but only started actively participating in the last few months.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

### Question 1

Regarding https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23919775/opening-text-files-on-remote-linux-machine-within-client-installed-smultron, I don't see anything that glaringly merits a downvote, but I don't often open editors on remote machines anymore, so I'm not a domain expert.

You tagged your question with `[linux]` and `[text-editor]` though, and there's a close vote on the question saying that it's off-topic because it belongs on [Super User](https://superuser.com/), so I guess maybe someone thought that the question wasn't really sufficiently programming related and that it was a better fit there? I don't know, I'm just guessing.

### Question 2

As for [Correct Path for Git Remote Add from Amazon EC2 Instance to OSX Client Machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23793657/correct-path-for-git-remote-add-from-amazon-ec2-instance-to-osx-client-machine), again, nothing really stands out to me as obviously being worthy of a downvote (though there isn't much that would compel me to upvote either). It's a "meh" question (in just my personal opinion, other people may think otherwise).

Maybe someone thought it would have been a better fit on [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/)? I don't know.

### Your Account History

Taking a quick glance over [your question history](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3160817/filmnut?tab=questions), you currently have:

- 2 questions with score of 3,
- 4 questions with score of 0,
- 1 question with score of -1.

Unless you have deleted questions that I can't see, with a history like that, I wouldn't be too worried about the downvotes you got on those questions...but that's just my opinion.

Comment: 2 with +3 isn't bad at all for a newcomer :)

Comment: This is very helpful. Thank you. I was mostly worried because, when I went to a post a new question earlier today, SO was warning me that I was on the verge of being banned due to down-votes.

Comment: @filmnut well, if the Stack Overflow platform was giving you a warning, then I would definitely be concerned about question quality...do you have deleted questions that you're not telling us about?

Comment: @Cupcake: No. I don't have a deleted question. I should also say that, when I go to post a new question now, SO no longer gives me this warning. It seems that, as a result of me asking this Meta SO question, a number of people have up-voted my originally down-voted questions (the ones I linked to above), and as a result SO no longer considers me "at risk."

Comment: @filmnut, that's a success story then. Showing the desire to learn is something that's highly encouraged here so you showing that with this question has moved you to a more stable footing moving forward. Keep that mentality as you continue to develop your skills.

Comment: @filmnut Every 5 minutes I see questions that are **much** worse than the two examples you give, so I am sorry you came close to a question ban. Some people automatically downvote anything that they think should be closed, so be careful about asking questions that might be off-topic. There's nothing wrong with question 2, which only got 1 downvote - sometimes a question picks up a downvote for no clear reason.