# What is wrong with this question... not?

Tags: discussion

I am revisiting a much-disputed question: what is wrong with this post. The crazy thing is this: I'm completely changing the question. What is good about [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38676507/how-to-make-netbeans-use-c11)?

Every time I read this question, which happens to be my own, I keep wondering why it was upvoted. Most of the questions I have posted, have been downvoted, 90% of those votes, I have no idea why I received them. Same thing with this question, only I want to know why it was positively received by this community.

I have tried to milk this community for things, resources, or what have you, to write good questions, and even answers. But every time I do that, it is negatively received because it has been *"hashed and rehashed to the point where I want to smoke hash."*, as one moderator put it. So, I figured I would stop pursuing the negative things of life (what is wrong with posts), at least for now, and would start trying to find the good parts of life (what is awesome about these posts).

Contrary to some opinions, I do want to write quality posts, not act like some green virus running around the computer screen:) I have tried to get help trying to improve posts, but that didn't work well at all. Now I'm trying to do something slightly different, and hopefully this community will help me do everything I possibly can to improve my posts.

Comment: I cannot see anything wrong with that question, you posted the solutions you tried, fully described the problem and it is clear what you are asking, all on-topic. What I use as a rule of thumb for a good question is putting myself in an answerer shoes before asking to understand if a question  is answerable. This is quite hard because you already understand what you want, just clear your mind, read your question out loud to your mom, dad and cat, if it is capable to understand your problem, it's most likely a good question

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'm not a moderator, just someone who leaves snarky comments. I distinctly remember leaving that comment, but I cannot find it now in my history, so I assume you deleted the question on which it was left. I do, however, recall that it was not about a question you had asked on Stack Overflow, but rather some kind of meta-suggestion. I can't remember exactly what it was, but it was literally something that gets suggested about 6 times a day, like making comments mandatory for anyone who downvotes. It does get tiring to have the same conversations over and over, and it even gets to be where you don't have the patience to go dig up all the prior discussions to link them and/or close as a duplicate. The search feature on this website isn't great, but it *does* work…

That said, let me try and deal with some of the substance of your question. To be fair, I'm still not clear what you're asking here. You seem to simply be frustrated with your inability to ask a good question. That's a very understandable situation—writing a good question is *hard*. It's hard for everyone! It's hard to reason through the problem enough to formulate a decent question. It's hard to make it reproducible and come up with a minimal yet complete example that demonstrates the problem. It's hard to know how much background information to include, without [overwhelming people with a giant wall of text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36864894/scaling-the-non-client-area-title-bar-menu-bar-for-per-monitor-high-dpi-suppo). It's something that takes practice to get right, and more than anything, it takes a lot of effort. Brace yourself for failure; you will not succeed at crafting a good question every time.

And you certainly are not likely to succeed the first time. That's why we have an "edit" function, and a comment feature, so you can tweak your question as things occur to you when you come back with fresh eyes, and in response to questions/suggestions left by others.

There have been lots of questions asked and answered on Meta already about how to ask a good question. 90% of it boils down to *effort*, specifically putting in the time to do some *research*, trying to answer your own question. A lot of the time, putting in this legwork will produce the answer for you for free. If it doesn't, you'll get some critical background information that will be necessary in both composing your question and understanding the answers. If you haven't spent an *extensive* amount of time searching the Internet and reading things that seem related to your question, you probably haven't spent enough time doing research and are likely to get downvotes.

Practice this skill by searching Meta for previous Q&A about how to write a good question.

> What is good about [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38676507/how-to-make-netbeans-use-c11)?

1. It is narrowly scoped. You give a specific environment and version number (Netbeans 8.1 on Linux Mint), and a specific task that you wish to accomplish (compiling C++11 code).
2. You explain what you've already tried, what happened, why that didn't work, and what you expected to see happen instead.
3. You provide the debugging information that is available to you, like the build log, that will help experts zero in on the problem.
4. You explained some of your assumptions, and you included a caveat that you had tried to search for an answer to your problem online but failed to find anything applicable. (For some people, simply asserting that you did this is sufficient to deter downvotes; others don't care and will downvote you if you are actually lying, but assuming you're a trustworthy person, this isn't a question that has already been asked and answered a hundred times already.)
5. You edited in updates as you continued to work on solving your problem and try new things. (Although you don't really need to preface these with "Edit:".)

The question isn't perfect, but it's specific, answerable, and useful to others that might have the same problem. That's enough for one or two upvotes, which are what you've received.

> Contrary to some opinions, I do want to write quality posts, not act like some green virus running around the computer screen:)

I don't know who is accusing you of that. Not to rehash what I said at the beginning of this answer (pun intended), but if you interpreted my comment as doing so, I apologize. It was not meant as an insult to you personally. I cannot recall having seen any specific, virus-like behavior on your part. The Meta community *can* be very helpful, but you have to:

1. Be prepared for some humor. It is not only the culture of Meta, but also a very important way to let off some steam, given the topics that we deal with here. Don't take things personally.
2. Do some background research. Become minimally acquainted with the site's policies and standards. (Same thing on main.) Don't ask or suggest things that have been asked or suggested thousands of times already. Don't suggest things that go directly against the site's core mission.
3. Be constructive. Post questions, instead of rants. (Not saying you're doing this.)
4. Focus on *specific* things that can be improved/specific issues that can be answered.. Asking how to improve a *specific question* is fine. Asking "why has my question been downvoted" is a good way to attract downvotes to your Meta question. It looks like you're (A) whining, (B) calling the premise of downvoting into question. Meta'ers do not react positively to either.

---

[Here's another question you recently asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38644485/how-can-the-program-user-choose-the-number-and-names-of-class-objects-at-runtime). It's received 4 close votes at the moment, and has a score of +1/-1. It is a *very poor* question. I struggle to understand why you cannot see that for yourself. Compare it to the question you asked about here. Just from length alone, you can assume that it probably doesn't have enough information. There is no code, there is no mention of your environment, there is no description of what you've already tried or what ideas you've had…nothing. The question is far too broad, underspecified, and difficult to answer.

Stack Overflow does not work well in situations where you have no idea where to start, or even how to explain your problem. It is not a personal consulting service, nor is it a debugging service. You have to have some minimal understanding of the problem. Q&A has to be reasonably scoped; we can't write an entire book to answer your question, and we won't write an entire project's worth of code. We also *don't want to guess*, so questions that are underspecified are bad because they lead to guessing and an inability to objectively judge the correctness of each answer.

[Here's another recent question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38294250/class-objects-declared-to-not-be-members-of-the-class). Wow, −13. Yeah, I see how that can be a bit disheartening. Some of that is the nature of the C++ tag. C++ programmers seem to have a keen eye for quality. In particular, they *demand it*. When it is presented, they reward it, but when it isn't, they come out against it with their votes. This is, all in all, a good thing, but it can come across as unwelcoming.

This is one of those questions that confuzzles an experienced C++ programmer. They can't figure out what in the world you are asking. Or, more accurately, they can't figure out *what you want to know*. You're asking about something that seem really simple and basic, something that could be answered by looking in any C++ textbook and/or having a minimal understanding of the language. So they either downvote your question because it's not useful, or they downvote your question because it is not clear what you're actually asking.

Are you literally asking us to explain the compiler error to you? It seems quite self-explanatory. What *specifically* were you confused about? You don't tell us. That makes it "unclear what you're asking". Someone has to guess. Don't make us guess.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38231311/how-to-declare-a-reference-to-a-member-in-the-same-class) isn't perfect, but it's acceptable. It didn't impress anyone enough to get any upvotes, but it also didn't catch anyone's ire enough to get downvotes or close votes. You even got a good, concise answer. Why? Because you told us what you were trying to do, posted sample code that reproduced the problem, included the specific compiler error messages, and explained the part that you were confused about.

Comment: This is the post with the quote, if you want to look at it. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/332296/how-do-we-write-good-questions-and-answers

Comment: Thanks for the very thorough answer. It answers a lot of my questions.

Comment: Well, you will be very disappointed if you keep looking for a formula, @veni. There is no formula for a good question. You will get partway there if you make sure not to leave out important bits, but there's still a big gulf between "acceptable" and "good". I would recommend spending some time browsing other questions in the C++ tag. Not only will you learn a lot about C++ (I spend a lot of time just reading Q&A and learning new things), but you'll also learn by example what a good question (and a bad question) is. It's really something you have to get a feel for; no substitute for experience.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I guess I'll be up for a lot more frustration before it's all over.

Comment: This answer reads to me like the non-tl;dr version of this other [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261593)